# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in SWIFT 3.0

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am using tableview with custom cell in swift 3.0. I take a textview and give outlet of class of tabelview cell and accessing in tableview delegate method but its showing me error like **unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

here is my code. **Record is array**

Chek this Screenshot. FYI I have taken A new custom class and Give Outlet to it but same problem ocuured

[image: Screenshot]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return record.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

  if let str = record.object(at: indexPath.row) as? String {
        print(cell.txtview)

            cell.txtview.text = str  

    }


    return cell
}
```

Its perfectly working in Static cell but in custom cell it showing me error.

**`cell.textview` is not taken from custom cell**

[image]

Please help me with it

Comment: what is the identifier of your custom cell, check that because of that might be the issue

Comment: As per My code I gave it same Class and same identifier. But identifier is given as string so Its not an issue

Comment: No @JAL Its in siwft 3.0, If its in swift 2.0 or lower then I had solved it

Comment: Read the linked duplicate.  It is Swift language version agnostic.

Comment: @JAL you can not give its duplicate question because its lots of changes in swift 2.0 and swift 3.0 and ya no thats question is not a custom cell its tableview default cell .

Comment: Is your textview outleted? Means have you mapped it with cell(xib or from storyboard)?

Comment: @MehulSojitra Yeah ,I Give outlet of textview withing tableviewcell class

Comment: Is this issue occuring on which line? its on :- cell.textview.text = string! as String ??

Comment: Ya, Error occur that line

Comment: Please see my edited answer imay be its halpful

Comment: @MehulSojitra check my updated question

Comment: Please remove mapping of your text view and map it again. And make sure that is mapped with tableview cell.

Comment: Please attached screenshot of mapping.

Comment: @MehulSojitra Check my question, I put Screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125767/discussion-between-mehul-sojitra-and-jecky).

Comment: Guys, Just try this thing once and test it in xcode 8 If you dont found this error then downvote it

Comment: I am using XIB for custom cell

Comment: You are using a nib (Xib) file, so you can't simply dequeue the cell and expect outlets to be connected. That only works for prototype cells in storyboards. If you want to use a nib then you need to explicity load the nib if a cell can't be dequeued. You need to use `dequeueReusableCell` without passing an index path and then check for nil. If you get nil then load a new cell class instance from the nib. Using storyboards and prototype cells is much easier and you could use your existing code

Comment: I have done in swift 2.2 ,xcode 7.3  and its working perfectly but I found this issue in swift 3.0, xcode 8.0

Comment: Can you show the code where you are registering your nib and class for the reuse identifier.

Comment: @Paulw11 In tableview delegate method I write code for registering nib file. I also tried that code in viewdidload but nothing helps

Comment: I just set up a quick test project in xcode8 that uses a Xib file and it worked without any issues. You should register the nib in viewdidload

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you send me project on jiten.benzatine@gmail.com ? Please I need to know why its crashing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125775/discussion-between-paulw11-and-jecky).

Answer (score -1):

Please try with following line not sure about that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        if let title = record.object(at: indexPath.row) as? String {
                cell.textview.text = title
        } else {
                cell.textview.text = ""
        }

        return cell
}
```

Comment: Which text did you got in title? - can you please post here.

Comment: I got this "I have a UITextView in a custom UITableViewCell. The textview delegate is assigned in the tableviewcell custom class." from array value